# How to avoid duplicate items being added from one CheckBoxList to another CheckBoxList (Asp.net vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 5 checkboxlists. each checkbox has 6 checkboxes inside it (below is my database)

checkboxlist1 : rowa

checkboxlist2:rowb

checkboxlist3:rowc

checkboxlist4:rowd

checkboxlist5:rowe

> id       : int,
>   rowa : bit,
>   rowb : bit,
>   rowc : bit,
>   rowd : bit,
>   rowe : bit,

rowtext:nvarchar(50)

My problem is , When adding items from one CheckBoxList  to another CheckBoxList

,how to check if the item is already present in the second  , third , forth , fifth CheckBoxLists ?

this is my code

```
    Protect sub_button1
```

'A CheckBoxList
        For a As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1

```
        If CheckBoxList1.Items(a).Selected Then
            rowtext = CheckBoxList1.Items(a).Text
            rowa = 1
            rowb = 0
            rowc= 0
            rowd= 0

            Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO tbtest(rowtext,rowa,rowb,rowc,rowd,) VALUES(@rowtext,@rowa,@rowb,@rowc,@rowd)"

            Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                myConnection.Open()
                Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowtext", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowtext
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowa", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowa
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowb
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowc", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowc
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowd", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowd
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myConnection.Close()
            End Using
        End If

    Next

    'B CheckBoxList
    For b As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList2.Items.Count - 1

        If CheckBoxList2.Items(b).Selected Then
            rowtext = CheckBoxList2.Items(b).Text
             rowa = 0
            rowb = 1
            rowc= 0
            rowd= 0
            Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO tbtest(rowtext,rowa,rowb,rowc,rowd) VALUES(@rowtext,@rowa,@rowb,@rowc,@rowd)"

            Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                myConnection.Open()
                Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowtext", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowtext
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowa", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowa
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowb
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowc", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowc
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowd", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowd
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myConnection.Close()
            End Using
        End If

    Next
```

'C CheckBoxList
        For c As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList3.Items.Count - 1

```
        If CheckBoxList3.Items(c).Selected Then
            rowtext = CheckBoxList3.Items(c).Text
             rowa = 0
            rowb = 0
            rowc= 1
            rowd= 0
            Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO tbtest(rowtext,rowa,rowb,rowc,rowd) VALUES(@rowtext,@rowa,@rowb,@rowc,@rowd)"

            Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                myConnection.Open()
                Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowtext", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowtext
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowa", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowa
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowb
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowc", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowc
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowd", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowd
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myConnection.Close()
            End Using
        End If

    Next
```

'D CheckBoxList
        For d As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList4.Items.Count - 1

```
        If CheckBoxList4.Items(d).Selected Then
            rowtext = CheckBoxList4.Items(d).Text
             rowa = 0
            rowb = 0
            rowc= 0
            rowd= 1
            Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO tbtest(rowtext,rowa,rowb,rowc,rowd) VALUES(@rowtext,@rowa,@rowb,@rowc,@rowd)"

            Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                myConnection.Open()
                Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowtext", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowtext
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowa", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowa
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowb", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowb
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowc", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowc
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowd", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rowd
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                myConnection.Close()
            End Using
        End If

    Next



    Catch ex As Exception


    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i would just use a recursive loop to check all the boxes before i put them into the DB.

i can write up the code in a min..

```
     Dim listofCheckBoxLists As New List(Of CheckedListBox)
'first to gather the info
For i = 1 To 4
    Dim checkboxlists As CheckedListBox = Me.Controls.Find("CheckedListBox" & i, True)(0)
    listofCheckBoxLists.Add(checkboxlists)
Next

'now to go through it all
For a = 0 To listofCheckBoxLists.Count - 1
    For b = 0 To listofCheckBoxLists(a).Items.Count - 1
        For c = a To listofCheckBoxLists.Count - 1
            For d = 0 To listofCheckBoxLists(c).Items.Count - 1
                If listofCheckBoxLists(a).Items(b) = listofCheckBoxLists(c).Items(d) Then
                    '''here should be where if they are the same you can do something
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but i'm coding on web form and i want to show only not duplicated value , how can i do that ?

Comment: then its me.findcontrol and your duplicate will be inside the if statment